# Pie (radial) menu for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, menu, radial

Does anyone know of a library -- open source or otherwise -- that I can use to create a pie (radial) menu for an iOS application?

[image]

It seems like someone should have thought of this by now, and I'd hate to roll my own if I don't have to.

Comment: i am also finding this if you got it then please share with me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One I found a while ago.

http://www.tapsandswipes.com/frameworks/touchpie/

https://github.com/tapsandswipes/iphone-pie-menu

Hasn't had an update since 2009, but when I looked at it back then it seamed sane and could be a good starting point for you at least.

chris.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one. Might be what you are looking for. You can customize all the spacing and positions.

[JVFlowerMenu](https://github.com/joninsky/JVFlowerMenu)

[image]